# Unusual characters when defining where to replace / alter string

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

I have to see if the array given (arr) is in ascending order. (only positive integers given)

I created an array for something to compare it against. Then looped through the input arr to see if each iteration matches. Or at least that was my goal.

Have also tried a counter variable which adds one to the count only every time sorted[i] == arr[i] is true. Then if the count is the same as sorted.length it is true. However, the fact this didn't work made me think I have made a more fundamental error somewhere.

```
function inAscOrder(arr) {
  let sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === sorted[i]) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Where are you replacing/altering strings?

Comment: `sort` mutates the array. So, `arr === sorted`. And, this function will `return` after index 0

Comment: A `return` statement exits the function immediately.

Comment: Thank you @Pointy that was the fundamental error :)

Answer (score 1):

`sort` modifies array in place, so you're comparing two identical arrays. You need to use `.slice()` on the array first to create a copy.

Also, you need to move `return true` to the end of the function, otherwise you will return after first match.

Answer (score 0):

```
function inAscOrder(arr) {
  return JSON.stringify(arr) === JSON.stringify(arr.concat().sort()));
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer to help others understand it better. Code only answers are considered impolite and it may not help the OP understand the problem that you are trying to help with.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to sort your array to check if it's sorted. Loop over each consecutive pair of elements and check if the first is less than the second; if you find a pair for which this isn't true, the array is not sorted.

```
function inAscOrder(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
      if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) {
          return false;
      }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: if you have huge arrays, this function will be faster

Comment: This is the optimized code. You could delete your previous answer. And if you wish to include, edit in this answer itself.